# Creating n processes for iterative task in python

Tags: python, process, locking, multiprocessing

I have a complexed problem with python multiprocessing module.
I have build a script that in one place has to call a multiargument function (call_function) for each element in a specyfic list. My idea is to define an integer 'N' and divide this problem for single sub processes.

```
li=[a,b,c,d,e] #elements are int's
for element in li:
    call_function(element,string1,string2,int1)

call_summary_function()
```

Summary function will analyze results obtained by all iterations of the loop. Now, I want each iteration to be carried out by single sub process, but there cannot be more than N subprocesses altogether. If so, main process should wait until 1 of subprocesses end and then perform another iteration. Also, call_sumary_function need to be called after all the sub processes finish.

I have tried my best with multiprocessing module, Locks and global variables to keep the actual number of subprocesses running (to compare to N) but every time i get error.

//--------------EDIT-------------//

Firstly, the main process code:

```
MAX_PROCESSES=3
lock=multiprocessing.Lock()
processes=0
k=0
while k < len(k_list):

    if processes<=MAX_PROCESSES: # running processes <= 'N' set by me

        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=single_analysis, args=(k_list[k],main_folder,training_testing,subsets,positive_name,ratio_list,lock,processes))
        p.start()
        k+=1

    else: time.sleep(1)


while processes>0: time.sleep(1)
```

Now: the function that is called by multiprocessing:

```
def single_analysis(k,main_folder,training_testing,subsets,positive_name,ratio_list,lock,processes):

lock.acquire()
processes+=1
lock.release()

#stuff to do

lock.acquire()
processes-=1
lock.release()
```

I get the Error that int value (processes variable) is always equal to 0, since `single_analysis()` function seems to create new, local variable `processes`.
When I change processes to global and import it in `single_analysis()` with `global` keyword and type `print processes in` within the function I get `len(li)` times 1...

Comment: Can you show the code (using `multiprocessing`) you have tried (that gives an error)?

Comment: The multiprocessing.Pool class may do what you want. It does the work of keeping N children alive for you. Have you tried it?

Comment: Tom Dalton: Done, I added specyfic description :)
tdelaney: I have red that using Pool you cannot call function with multiple arguments.

Comment: @maciek You can call functions with multiple arguments using `Pool`. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is pefectly suited for [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) - specifically its [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map) method:

```
import multiprocessing
from functools import partial

def call_function(string1, string2, int1, element):
    # Do stuff here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    li=[a,b,c,d,e]
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(N)  # The pool will contain N worker processes.

    # Use partial so that we can pass a method that takes more than one argument to map.
    func = partial(call_function, string1,string2,int1)

    results = p.map(func, li)
    call_summary_function(results)
```

`p.map` will call `call_function(string1, string2, int1, element)`, for each `element` in the `li` list. `results` will be a list containing the value returned by each call to `call_function`. You can pass that list to `call_summary_function` to process the results.

Comment: Thank You very much!
I tried Pool() before, but I was missing 'partial'
You saved the day :)